# How do I use ?: in Swift?

Tags: swift, conditional-operator, infix-operator

I love this syntax in Objective-C, where a question mark and colon let you use a backup value:

```
NSString const name = [self getName] ?: @"backup";
```

and I want to use the same in Swift, but I get this when I try:

[image: <code>let name = getName() ?: "backup";</code> results in errors where the compiler completely doesn't recognize the syntax]

**Is there any way to do this in Swift?** If not, can I write a custom infix operator to do it?

Comment: Oh, it's called "null coalescing"? Thanks! That's really helpful for Googling it.

Comment: Named "nil coalescing operator" for Swift. :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72

Answer (score 14):

It's called a **null (or nil) coalescing operator**, and the Swift syntax is:

```
let name = getName() ?? "backup";
```